Is there a way to use Python to convert a word document to txt, and encode pilicrows and check box answers in the txt document?
When I directly convert the word to txt it doesn't encode pilcrows or check box answers and I end up losing that information. I'm trying to get the same result as when I convert it to txt within the word document, but with the pilicrows and check box answers. ChatGPT gave me this code as an example, but the result txt file only has a few paragraphs from the word document and it is missing most of the information from when I directly convert the world file to txt.
from pathlib import Path
from docx import Document
def convert_docx_to_txt(input_file, output_file):
    # Load the Word document
    doc = Document(input_file)
    
    # Open the output file in write mode
    with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as txt_file:
        # Iterate through each paragraph in the document
        for para in doc.paragraphs:
            text = para.text
            
            # Replace form checkboxes with "Yes" or "No"
            # Note: The symbol for checkboxes might be different in some documents
            if '☒' in text:  # Checked box (you may need to adjust this symbol)
                text = text.replace('☒', 'Yes')
            if '☐' in text:  # Unchecked box
                text = text.replace('☐', 'No')
            
            # Write the processed text to the file
            txt_file.write(text + '\n')

Is this something I should even be doing with Python?

first try to import your word file into html, see if if on browser it is preserved or not

btw why not convert word into pdf, is it necessary to convert it into txt. how do you expect that text file will contain some sort of html backed word symbols and design.

I converted to html and the check box answers are not in it. Does that mean this won't work?

And I need to read the file into R to manipulate the information. I tried reading the PDF into R and it was also missing the check box answers from the word
